# Set Max Font Size in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Quick Question, how am i able to set the max font size so that the font wont get too big when resizing? my default font size is 22px, but using this code it goes up higher that the default.

```
<script>
    function resize_text(){
        resize = $(window).width()/50;
        min = 18;

        if(resize > min){
            $('p').css('font-size',resize + 'px'); 
            $('h1').css('font-size',resize + 'px'); 
            $('.bottom-list').css('font-size',resize + 'px'); 
        } else {
            $('p').css('font-size',min + 'px'); 
            $('h1').css('font-size',min + 'px'); 
            $('.bottom-list').css('font-size',min + 'px');
        }
    }
    $(window).resize(function(){
        resize_text();
    })

    </script>
```

Comment: I did something similar last year, I had created on plugin for that, http://jsfiddle.net/fruitjs/zpYb4/9/

Look if works for you, u can add the selectors, classes, ids in the settings

Comment: I just updated the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/fruitjs/zpYb4/10/

Answer (score 0):

You are using *resize = $(window).width()/50;* , where resize value may go beyond 22 .
If your default value is 22 , you may try this code :

```
resize = 22;
if($(window).width()/50 < 22){
     resize = $(window).width()/50
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing this with javascript, wy don't you do this with css?

```
p{font-size: 100%} or provide anyother percentage criteria as per your requirement.
```

I think it will resolve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the line that `resize` is defined on too:

```
newsize = $(window).width()/50;
resize = newsize > 22 ? 22 : newsize;
```